# How can I distribute custom Python scripts, including dependencies and other resources?

Tags: python, package, distutils, software-distribution, python-wheel

My project contains:

- My own custom Python files
- Unique package-specific generated Python code
- Resources (e.g. binaries)
- Dependencies on 3rd party modules (e.g. numpy)

The generated Python code makes things tricky, and separates this use case from a typical Python package where everyone gets the same code. I may create several packages to be distributed to different clients. Each package will have different/unique generated Python code, but use identical versions of my custom Python scripts and 3rd party dependencies. For example I may make a "package builder" script, which generates the unique Python code and bundles the dependencies together, depending on the builder arguments.

I want to distribute my Python scripts, including the resources and dependencies. The receiver of this package cannot download the 3rd party dependencies using a requirements.txt and pip; all dependencies and binaries must be included in this package.

The way I envision the client using this package is that they simply unzip the archive I provide, set their PYTHONPATH to the unzipped directory, and invoke my custom Python file to start the process.

If I'm going about this the wrong way I'd appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered using the standard distribution method (ie. setuptools, distutils)?  Why can't you use the standard methods of declaring dependencies in your setup.py script?

Comment: Have you tried [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org)?

Comment: @BrendanAbel while I could declare my dependencies (e.g. `install_requires=['numpy']` ) using setuptools, I have not yet seen a way to include the dependency files themselves. the client receiving the package will not be able to download and install the dependencies; I need to provide them as well. @Jimmy C I have not tried that; I will give it a shot. thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like py2app for Mac OS or py2exe for Windows? The last one is cool because it allows to use the generated .exe file to be executed from command line. You can also use Cython to translate your script to C and then compile as a standalone tool with almost no dependencies.